# When i pass a jframe as a parameter to another method, a blank frame appears

Tags: java, parameters, jframe

I am creating a small game, and there is a menu method with a button that starts the actual game. I only want one frame to do all this, but when i pass the jframe as a parameter to the game method, the game becomes a blank frame.

This is my code. I used debugger and found out that paint method is never called.

```
    public class GameMenu
    {
        public void start()
        {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(480,600);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);


      Background background = new Background(frame);
    }
}

    public class Background extends JPanel implements KeyListener , ActionListener
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private Player player1;
    private ObstacleControl obsControl;
    private SpeedBuffControl spdBuffControl;
    private ExtraLifeControl lifeControl;
    private Timer timer;
    private int lifeCount;
    private int xLeft;
    private int xRight;
    private int yDown;
    private int yUp;

    public Background(JFrame frame)
    {
        frame.add(this);
        startGame();
    }

    public void startGame()
    {
        timer = new Timer(20000,this);

        obsControl = new ObstacleControl(this);
        spdBuffControl = new SpeedBuffControl(this);
        lifeControl = new ExtraLifeControl(this);

        timer.start();
        player1 = new Player(this); 
        lifeCount = 3;
        xLeft = -4;
        xRight = 4;
        yDown = 4;
        yUp = -4;
    }

    public void resetPlayer()
    {
        if(lifeCount>1)
        {
            player1 = new Player(this);
            obsControl.resetObstacle();
            lifeCount--;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("you are dead");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        obsControl.increaseDifficulty();
        spdBuffControl.addBuff();
        lifeControl.addExtraLife();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(new Color(149,146,240));
        g.fillRect(0,0,480,600);
        player1.draw(g);
        obsControl.draw(g);
        spdBuffControl.draw(g);
        lifeControl.draw(g);
        g.dispose();
        repaint();
    }
```

Comment: You should describe your problem with a code sample if possible. This description is not enough to give you an answer. Also have you tried debugging for uncaught exceptions by setting breakpoints in your code?

Answer (score 2):

Swing is lazy about when it updates the layouts

Instead of

```
frame.setVisible(true);
Background background = new Background(frame);
```

you should do...

```
Background background = new Background(frame);       
frame.setVisible(true);
```

But that begs the question of why you'd bother, instead, you really should be doing...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setSize(480,600);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(new Background());
frame.setVisible(true);
```

and not pass the `JFrame` to the `Background`, it has no need for it

This is wrong on so many levels...

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(new Color(149,146,240));
    g.fillRect(0,0,480,600);
    player1.draw(g);
    obsControl.draw(g);
    spdBuffControl.draw(g);
    lifeControl.draw(g);
    g.dispose();
    repaint();
}
```

- As a matter of preference, you should be using `paintComponent` instead of `paint`
- You should be calling the methods `super` method before doing any custom painting
- You should not be calling `dispose` on a `Graphics` context you did not create
- You should not be calling `repaint` (or calling any method which might call `repaint`) from within a paint method

Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details